# Partial view get returned but Browser shows nothing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have view in which a search takes place, I then pass everything to my controller which in turn searches and returns a partial view. 
**When I debug the view I can see that the model I pass is correct, but nothing shows up in the browser?** 
***Possible solution***
Do I need to append everything in the ajax callback function since the both views are already rendered?

Everything gets called the model I pass the partial view has the results, when debugging the "Result" view it does iterate over the model, and everything appears fine. But the browser shows nothing? As if it does not update the dom accordingly?!

Here's my code!

**MAIN VIEW**

```
<div style="width: 700px; margin-top: 30px;">
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
   <table id="certificate">
     <thead> Certificates</thead>
     <tbody>

     </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <table id="courses">
      <thead> Courses</thead>
       <tbody>

      </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <table id="prevexp">
       <thead> Previous Exp.</thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
  <table id="country">
       <thead>Countries</thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
 </table>
```

```
@Html.Partial("Result", new MvcApplication2.Models.ViewModel.Search.SearchResult())
</div>
```

**Result VIEW**
    @model MvcApplication2.Models.ViewModel.Search.SearchResult

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Result";
 }

<h2>Result</h2>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults) {

<tr>
    <td> <b>
       @item.Value.FirstName  @item.Value.SurName
        </b>
    </td>

</tr>


foreach (var ic in item.Value.Certificates)
{  <tr>
    <td>
    @ic.CertificateName --  @ic.SearchType
    </td>

     </tr>
}


}
</table>
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
 $('#ajaxsearchbutton').live("click", function (e) {
    var form = {};
    form = $("#theform").serialize()
    $.post("Search", form, function (data) {
        alert("I'm Callbacked");
    });
 });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  return PartialView("Result", _sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I needed to append the data from the partial view, I did it by doing this

First i gave the partial view table an ID.

```
<h2>Result</h2>
//UPDATED ID HERE!!!
<table ="tabletoupdate">
@foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults) {

<tr>
<td> <b>
   @item.Value.FirstName  @item.Value.SurName
    </b>
</td>

</tr>


foreach (var ic in item.Value.Certificates)
{  <tr>
<td>
@ic.CertificateName --  @ic.SearchType
</td>

 </tr>
}


}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $('#ajaxsearchbutton').live("click", function (e) {
  var form = {};
  form = $("#theform").serialize()
  $.post("Search", form, function (data) {

  //HERE I ADDED THE ID OF THE TABLE AND THE DATA THAT WAS RETURNED   

    $('#tabletoupdate').html(data);

    alert("I'm Callbacked");
   });
  });
```